# OuterRef is compatible with UUID Django

Tags: django, postgresql, model, subquery

I have the following query where the primary key of the products model is a UUID and when I use OuterRef in the query it throws me the following message:

```
ValidationError at /api/v1/productstodist/
["'0' it is not a valid UUID."]
```

OuterRef does not support uuid?

the following is the query that I am trying to perform between two models:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(~Q(provider = provider)).annotate(
            sellproductprices=Subquery(
                prefetch_qr.filter(product=OuterRef('pk'))
                    .values('id_sell_price')
                    .annotate(count=Count('pk'))
                    .values('count')
            )
        ).filter(
            sellproductprices__gt=0
        ).prefetch_related(
            prefetch
        )
```

Comment: You get a `ValidationError` which normally occurs when one is handling a _form_ or uses one of the model's clean method. Furthermore the error is `'0' it is not a valid UUID.`. Meaning the code you show and the error **don't** match. Please add the _full_ traceback of the error to the question and see how to write a [mre].

Comment: the 0 that appears in the ValueError is the one in the filter: sellproductprices__gt=0. I just don't know how to call the value that is taking into account from the filter of the Queryset